# Magento 1.9 version Custom discount is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, discount, grand-total, subtotal

I am using these 2 observers -

1 - sales_quote_collect_totals_after

2 - sales_order_place_before

Custom discount(which is 3%) is working fine when customer do order from Cash on delivery but customer pay via online then it is not working.

I am using USAePay payment method.

Note:Discount(10% using coupon code) is working fine for both cash on delivery and USAePay payment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do have any specific condition to give the custom discount? or for all orders

Comment: yes,you are right.There is a specific condition when customer fill form then we are giving 3% discount to that customer(who fill-up the form)

Comment: can you go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878934/magento-how-to-add-custom-discount-without-using-coupon-code-in-observer) one, maybe something you missed

Comment: @Hit's i add other snapshot(updated) after try your link getting in negative row total.
Here i am giving 10% and 3% discount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem,the problem is wrong calculations here -
So changed from -

```
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $rat = $item->getPriceInclTax() / $total;
    $ratdisc = $discountAmount * $rat;
    $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount()));
    $item->setBaseDiscountAmount($item->getBaseDiscountAmount())->save();
}
```

To -

```
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $rat=$item->getPriceInclTax()/$total;
    $ratdisc=$discountAmount*$rat;
    $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
    $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();
}
```